# Get variable value with a string in scheme

Tags: scheme, lisp, common-lisp

How can we get variable value with a string in scheme language as we can achieve this in Common Lisp:

```
> (defvar s 3) 
> S
> (symbol-value (intern "S"))
> 3
```

I am accessing a parameter of parent function from the closure.

**EDIT:** I have found this solution, but I can't use eval because it evaluates at top level. Searching for alternatives.

```
(eval (string->symbol "s"))
```

**EDIT 2:** I have found that Common lisp code also try to find symbol in global space. So this question is basically for both Lisps(Common Lisp, Scheme).

Comment: Are you performing string interpolation ?

Comment: You can't access a lexical variable in a lexical closure in Common Lisp via a string name. The DEFVAR example is about dynamic/special variables.

Comment: I realized that, so no solution?

Comment: Maybe it is an X-Y-Problem? https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

You could have a certain problem, accessing a variable by name could be an approach - which then does not work. But there might be a solution for your original problem?

Comment: Thank you, trying to get around.

Comment: Common Lisp  does not have a global space. The default package  for interning symbols is usually `user` (often called `cl-user`). `user` uses the package `lisp`. It is possible to create packages that do not use `lisp` and creating a package that does not use `lisp` is a common error when learning about Common Lisp packages.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't do that!

Variables are for when you know the variable at compile time. In that case it is **never** a string. You can still reason about strings in compile time but your code also needs to have a relation with the name for it to be interesting. When you use `eval` or other forms that evaluate structure and compile/run data in runtime you are probably not doing it right (but not always. I've in my 20 year career used `eval` intentionally in production code twice)

If you want to store values you use a data structure. An assoc would mimic a dynamic environment. You can also use a hash with a level indicator if the size is harmless.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do what you want to do and in fact it is a confused thing to want to do.

Here's why what you are trying to do is confused.  Consider how a Lisp system for which it *was* possible to do what you wanted would work.  In particular consider something like this:

```
(define (foo a name)
  (let ([b 10])
    (display (get-value name))
    (* a b)))
```

Where `get-value` is meant to be how you get the binding of whatever something is.

So, if I call `(foo 10 "b")` it should print `10` and return `100`.

But wait: `b` is a compile-time constant in this code.  Any compiler worth its salt is going to immediately turn this into

```
(define (foo a name)
  (display (get-value name))
  (* a 10))
```

And now there *is no binding of `b`*.

So there are two options here: what you want to work works and it is impossible to ever write a reasonable compiler for Scheme, or what you want to work doesn't work, and it is.